# Magento can’t add new attribute options

Tags: magento-1.9

While I was working with magento I got stuck on a strange problem, Magento freezes everytime I try to add more then one attribute value at once. To use the layered navigation in magento for filtering the 350 types of brands I was creating dropdown attribute options. After 240 options magento wouldn’t save any new values and freezes on Please Wait…

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: Product attribute option didn't update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update or delete attribute options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68406/cant-update-or-delete-attribute-options)

Answer (score 3):

To use the layered navigation in magento for filtering the 350 types of brands I was creating dropdown attribute options. After 240 options magento wouldn’t save any new values and freezes on Please Wait…

The following part did the trick.
1. Open php.ini
2. Alter or Add the following lines:

```
; Input Vars
max_input_vars = 100000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 100000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 100000

; Memory Limit
memory_limit = 256M

; Time
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 600

; Posts
post_max_size = 512M
```

Restart apache and the problem is solved.